# PGFPlots only have one 0 at the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I create a figure using tikzpicture, tikz adds two 0's at the origin for a plot (one for the x-axis and another for the y-axis). I think it looks cleaner to only have one zero at the origin. I don't want to manually adjust xtick and ytick and was hoping for a smarter way to do this. Did I miss something in the PGFPlots manual?

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen when the two axes don't cross at the origin but 0 lies in the x-range and y-range of the data? Surely you would want one zero for each axis in such a case...

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You can also use the option `\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle] ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built-in code for this, but you can create a style to do it if you want. Here, I've created `ignore zero` which accepts a single argument: the axis for which the zero ticklabel will not be plotted:

```
\pgfplotsset{ignore zero/.style={%
  #1ticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=0pt \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi}
}}
```

That just compares the current value of `\tick` on the specified axis to zero. If it is zero, we do nothing; if it's not zero, proceed with normal ticklabel typesetting (`\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}`). Here's an example showing both possibilities (ignoring either `x` or `y`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{ignore zero/.style={%
  #1ticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=0pt \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi}
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,domain=0:5,ignore zero=x]
  \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,domain=0:5,ignore zero=y]
  \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can further improve the apperance by modifying the labels. Say you have `ignore zero=y`, than you can say `xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5}` and `xticklabels={{0~~~},1,2,3,4,5}`. No really nice coding but it gets the job done.